# Ember call a action handler from normal Javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am working in Ember with my existing jQuery. Now I need to call a action handler in my Router from my jQuery method.

My Route:

```
App.ApplicationRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        updateFolder: function(obj){
             //Need to update my model using the obj.
        }
    }
});
```

My JavaScript method:

```
// Native Javascript code. 
function updateFolderModel(obj){
    // Need to call the action handler in my application route. How to call from here.
}
```

How can I call Ember action handlers from normal native JavaScript methods.

Comment: You dont have to use it between action brackets(updateFolder). Also you do have access to your model in controller as well. http://dpaste.com/23V0EAM If you provided more code... Would make more sense.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold Thanks for your reply. The method updateFolderModel(); is not in Ember Controller, its my native javascript. From my native JavaScript I need to call an action handler in my Ember code.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold all actions have to be present inside action brackets itself unless its just a method!!!

Comment: @Jeevi you can call action handlers from components using this.send('action',data).
When you say updateFolderModel is my native javascript where is it present? inside route/controller/view?

Comment: @Wishy It is present in my normal javascript file. It is not inside route/controller/view/component/model. Its a js file which has all my function written using jQuery

Comment: then i dont think you have understood the purpose of Ember. Ember is a framework. So if you create an application using ember everything has to be inside an ember defined concept such as utils/views/routes/ and it is strictly not advised to do otherwise. As a matter of fact you wont be able to work many things prperly if you try to merge

Comment: @Wishy Oh yeah ive forgotten about the send('action', data) my bad

Comment: @Wishy , I agree with you, but only part of my application is in Ember. The other part which is depends on other modules are in jQuery. So I am not in a situation to migrate all the code to Ember.

Comment: see if this helps you
http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/

Also i would not suggest using ember as only half of ur application, however if you still want to. Try to use the var that holds the application i.e. app = Ember.Application.Create and then use app.yourView.someFunction() and inside the someFunction have a this.get('controller').send('actionName',data); This should serve your purpose

Comment: @Wishy I could not get app.yourView.someFunction(), when I call the function throws an error as undefined.

Comment: have you initialized your view? meaning var viewInst = new EmberViewName();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want your outside code to know about your Ember application. The best way to deal with this in this case is using DOM events. DOM events would be the means of communication between your Ember application and the "outside world". See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_responding-to-browser-events for some documentation on this.

For instance

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  // See comment by @Wishy
  click: function() {
    this.send('actionThatWillBeSentToYourRoute');
  },
  /*
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    // Replace 'click' with a custom DOM event
    this.$().on('click', function() {
      Ember.run(self, function() {
        this.send('actionThatWillBeSentToYourRoute');
      });
    });
  }
  */
});
```

The `Ember.run` is required because you want to run the callback inside the Ember runloop. Note that it is a bit cleaner to register your custom DOM events as in http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_customEvents.

Then in your Route you would have

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    actionThatWillBeSentToYourRoute: function() { ... }
  }
});
```

Note that you can define your own custom DOM events, for instance an event `updateFolder`. Then you can do

```
function updateFolderModel(obj){
  $.trigger('updateFolder', obj);
}
```

I hope this is of any help!

Comment: why do you want to do didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    // Replace 'click' with a custom DOM event
    this.$().on('click', function() {
      Ember.run(self, function() {
        this.send('actionThatWillBeSentToYourRoute');
      });
    });.
you could just do
click:function(){}. Views are meant to handle events and there is no separate need to register event handlers